# arning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)

Tags: reactjs

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import TodoList from './components/Todolist';
    import AddTodo from './components/AddTodo';
    import SearchTodo  from './components/SearchTodo';

    class App extends Component {
     constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        todos:[{
          id:uuid(),
          text: 'learn React',
          completed:false
        },
        {
          id:uuid(),
          text: 'Cut your hair',
          completed:false
        },
        {
          id: uuid(),
          text: 'go to church',
          completed: true
        }],
        searchVal: '',
        showCompleted: false
      }
      this.handleAddTodo = this.handleAddTodo.bind(this)
      this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)
      this.toggleTodo = this.toggleTodo.bind(this)
      this.filterTodos = this.filterTodos.bind(this)
    }
      handleAddTodo(inputValue){
        this.setState({
          todos:[
            ...this.state.todos,
            {
              id: uuid(),
              text: inputValue,
              completed: false
            }
          ]
        })
      }
      toggleTodo(id){
        var updatedTodo = this.state.todos.map((todo) => {
          if(todo.id === id){
            todo.completed = !todo.completed;
          }
          return todo
        });
        console.log(updatedTodo.completed)
        this.setState({
          todos: updatedTodo,
        })
      }
      handleSearch(searchVal, showCompleted){
        this.setState({
          searchVal: searchVal.toLowerCase(),
          showCompleted: showCompleted
        })
      }

      // Error here
      filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchVal){
        var filteredTodos = this.state.todos;
        filteredTodos = filteredTodos.filter((todo) => {
          var text = todo.text.toLowerCase();
          return this.state.searchVal.length === 0 || todo.indexOF(searchVal) > -1
        })
        this.setState({
          todos: filteredTodos
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <SearchTodo onSearch={this.handleSearch}/>
           <TodoList todos={this.state.todos} onToggle={this.toggleTodo} filterTodos={this.filterTodos}/>
           <AddTodo handleAdd={this.handleAddTodo}/>
           </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

> I am attempting a todo list app in react. When trying to write a method to filter the list I created I come across the above mentioned error, I am wondering what I am doing wrong.
>
> Otherwise what is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lays out in this line:

`var filteredTodos = this.state.todos;`

Since `this.state.todos` is an array, you are assigning the same reference to `filteredTodos`.

That will make the state to be **mutated** in the next chunk of code, unwittingly causing React to schedule an update. Your code is equivalent to:

```
this.state.todos = filteredTodos.filter((todo) => {
   var text = todo.text.toLowerCase();
   return this.state.searchVal.length === 0 || todo.indexOF(searchVal) > -1
})
```

Therefore, when you setState on the next line, React will yell at you with that warning since a *corrupt* update is in progress.

```
 this.setState({
   todos: filteredTodos
 })
```

To work around the issue, you should create a shallow copy of the state prior to filtering. Remember to **never** mutate the state in your components, it should be always considered as **read-only** value and **immutable**. Create copies when you are dealing with arrays and objects. Filter method from Arrays itself return always a new array:

```
filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchVal){
    var filteredTodos = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => {
      var text = todo.text.toLowerCase();
      return this.state.searchVal.length === 0 || todo.indexOf(searchVal) > -1
    })
    this.setState({
      todos: filteredTodos
    })
  }
```